# Google Icons are not displayed properly even on Google's Icon site

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, safari

## Problem

When I go to any site that uses Google's Icons, such as https://design.google.com/icons/, I only see a textual representation rather than the actual icon.

This is happening with chrome and firefox. In Safari, I merely see a blank space with no icon or text.

[image: screenshot of problem]

I am using macOS Sierra version 10.12, although this problem was also existent in El Capitan.

Note, that if I log in to the macOS guest account, things work perfectly, so there seems to be something in my user settings that is causing this.

## What I've Tried

1. Confirmed that the guest account can view the icons properly
2. Confirmed that a second user account can see the icons properly
3. Checked settings in all 3 browsers but was unable to find anything relevant. In Firefox there is a setting `Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above` but this was enabled. Toggling it did not help.
4. Checked for any application that may be causing this but could not find an obvious candidate
5. Searched on google but could not find anything useful, which is the reason I am finally posting on stack overflow.

As a nascent web developer, this is obviously something I would like to resolve barring the obvious which is a complete clean install and 1-by-1 re-install of my applications.

Comment: Check the console on the page. Having a similar problem here with the paths of the actual icon font files in relation of the css file packaged with it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I had downloaded the google design icons locally, and there was a conflict there. Google Chrome was trying to load the icons locally (and not finding them for some reason). Once I deleted the local copy, everything was resolved.